# Collision Detection - Character not falling of platform correct

Tags: three.js

I am making a platform game with movement in x and y axis. Im using the collision detction from https://stemkoski.github.io/Three.js/Collision-Detection.html, works great and all. Just that Im having a small problem that I do not understand how to solve. Did the reasearch and found nothing that helped me with the problem (probably because I dont get how it works).

To the problem: When Im moving my character left and right I want the character fall down where the ledge is, works on the left side. But on the right side the character starts to fall before where the ledge is [picture](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/108353435/threejs.png).

This is how my code looks like now:

```
function animate() {
    requestAnimationFrame( animate );
    var originPoint = user.position.clone();
    for (var i = 0; i < user.geometry.vertices.length; i++) {

        var localVertex = user.geometry.vertices[i].clone();
        var globalVertex = localVertex.applyMatrix4(user.matrixWorld);
        var directionVector = globalVertex.sub(user.position);

        var ray = new THREE.Raycaster(originPoint, directionVector.clone().normalize());

        var collisionResult = ray.intersectObjects(objectArray);

        if (collisionResult.length > 0 && collisionResult[0].distance < directionVector.length()){ 
            inAir = false;

        }
        else inAir = true;
    };


    var userGeometry = new THREE.PlaneGeometry( 50, 100, 10 );
    var userMaterial = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( {
        color: "red"
    } );

    var user = new THREE.Mesh( userGeometry, userMaterial );
    scene.add(user);
```

Comment: It looks like you have some syntax errors, like `user = my character.`, it's also bad form to have an `if` block with brackets (`{...}`) and its accompanying `else` block without them, you don't need a  semi-colon (`;`) following a `for` block.

Comment: I was just looking back over my edit, and noticed that `user = my character.` might not have been part of your code and was rather you stating that `user equals my character.`, sorry if that's the case.

Comment: Yes I only stated that, but changed it now so its not that confusing.